# How do I remove dust and fine hair artifacts in my photos?

Tags: photoshop, dust

There is a large streak along the left hand side of my picture. The detail of the picture is not occluded fully, but I lack the knowledge of how to remove it.

[image]

Zoomed detail of the affected area:

[image: zoomed detail]

I have access to a free trial of Photoshop.

Artistically speaking, I feel I need to 'lighten' the streak or maybe 'tint' it bluish.

What is the best way to do this in Photoshop? I've already tried the healing tools in Lightroom and some of the brushes to limited success.

Comment: i don't see a streak on the left side, only a shadow in the middle.

Comment: @ths updated my post

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE! I have edited your question to embed the zoomed detail image into the question, as well as editing the title to make it a little more descriptive of the problem. If you feel I have altered the meaning of your question, please feel free to revert my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be even more concerned to find out what is causing that streak. If this is a crop from even larger image, I would suspect there is some dust on the sensor or inside the lens.

However, I also did some experimenting on editor (Gimp in my case), and I would say you should try to increase the area of selection used with the healing tool. Try diameter same as the whole streak. You will loose some nice details but the result is still good enough, I think.

Healing tool also has different settings (at least it has on Gimp). I do recommend experimenting with them to get for example "lighter" effect.

EDIT: To make this suggestion more useful, I add also here the requested example. On this quick example I used only the basic heal tool settings. The idea and suggestion that I think works adequately in this case is to choose source area large enough for the heal tool. On this example image the source area I chose, is the circle on top right, and target is the circle on lower left. Also keep in mind that the audience does not know how the original looked.

[image: Heal on Gimp]

Comment: it is dust on the sensor, but this was unavoidable as I was shooting on the beach extensively.

Comment: Then to continue on the heal tool settings, try to decrease opacity, and try for example to change the 'Mode' (same as layer modes). That way you get smoother effects.

Comment: Could you show me an example of what your brief attempt looked like?

Comment: Sorry for belated reply. I stick with my very first suggestion to just choose an area large enough for the source. Here on my example image you'll see the source area (upper right circle) and target area (lower left circle. Click the link -> [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/92vce4hy9jj0hh3/gimp_heal.jpg?dl=0) I my self rather not to paint with heal tool but try to do that with series of "single shots" (clicks). Then in general it is good to keep in mind that the audience does not know what the original looked like ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the two simplest options in PS would be:

- Select the area with the lasso, then right click and fill with content aware.
- Use the patch tool (found along with the healing brush).  Select the area in question and then drag it horizontally.